# Secret Santa 100% reciprocity formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

In my company, we are *n* employees.
We've all picked our Secret Santa*ee*.
We know for sure nobody has picked his own name.
What are the odds that everyone has picked the one that has picked his name?
Eg: 1 picked 4 and 4 picked 1; 3 picked 5 and 5 picked 3; 2 picked 6 and 6 picked 2...
I've tried to create a formula but I think it's redundant:
*c* = number of couples = n/2
*e* = number of eligible people, for one person: n-1
The formula would be *e^(c-1)*
c-1 and not c, because the last "couple" can be guessed if all the others were found.
Can someone help me find the good formula? Thanks!

Comment: Not oddly, the odds are zero if $n$ is odd.

Comment: For the size of the sample space: look up "derangements".  For the size of the target, a standard overcounting argument (assuming $n$ is even) gives $\frac{n!}{2^{n/2} (n/2)!}$.

Answer (score 1):

For an even number of employees $2n$, we want permutations with all cycles of length two in the cycle decomposition out of the number of derangements $D_{2n}$, which are permutations without fixed points. There are 
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}
$$
ways to pair $2n$ people up. Also
$$
D_{2n}=(2n)!\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}.
$$
Hence the probability is
$$
\frac{1}{2^nn!\sum_{i=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I'm a math n00b and not able to understand the answer. I'll google this out until it makes sense to me :D